# How to compare two strings within a single line in java script

Tags: javascript, ui-automation

I got the String as :-Time in Queue,Item Type, Status,Type,Name, 22days, Document,Idle,Default,test4.

Now I have to compare status and its corresponding values as idle.

How to pick these two words in a single line and compare using java script.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you need to parse?

Comment: `"string1" === "string2"`

Comment: You might consider the possibility that you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is fixed, you could, for example, split the string

```
var result = "-Time in Queue,Item Type, Status,Type,Name, 22days, Document,Idle,Default,test4".split(",")[7] === 'Idle';
```

But I think you need something else, it is just unclear from the description. Probably if you added some context and described why you need this (why it must be single line, where the data came from, how they are really structured etc.), you could get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

...is there a line-break there, somewhere?

...you could do something like:

```
var string = "Time in Queue,Item Type,Status,Type,Name, 22days,Document,Idle,Default,test4",

    pieces = string.split(","),
    match = pieces[2].trim() === "Status" && pieces[6].trim() === "Idle";
```

...of course, `.trim` doesn't work on old browsers, but you can write something similar, easily.

If you really, really want to go golfing, you could do something like:

```
var string = "Time in Queue,Item Type,Status,Type,Name, 22days,Document,Idle,Default,test4",
    reg = /[^,]+,[^,]+,\s*Status\s*,[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,\s*Idle\s*/i;

reg.test(string);
```

This will tell you if "..., ...,  Status, ..., ..., ..., ..., Idle" happens in the string, where "..." is any set of characters which isn't a comma.

If that's not what you mean, then you need to get more specific, here.